# how i can modify the url of webview.goBack() before loading the url

Tags: java, android, webview

i have this code  for my onBackPressed function
they have any possibility to remove some caractere from url loaded when backpress ?
like if the url of webview.goBack() is :

https://website.com/userpanel/testlines.php?action=new_test_line

its possible to modify the url before loading it ?? like this  :

https://website.com/userpanel/testlines.php

remove all after the "?"
how i can modify the value of webview.goBack() ??

```
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if (!webview.isFocused() || !webview.canGoBack()) {
            new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                    .setTitle("EXIT")
                    .setMessage("Are you sure. You want to close this app?")
                    .setPositiveButton("Yes", (dialog, which) -> finish())
                    .setNegativeButton("No", null).show();
        } else {
            webview.goBack();
        }
    }
```

thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can try this, pass your url to this method and this will return back the URL without parameters

```
public static String getOnlyURL(String URL) throws URISyntaxException {
    URI uri = new URI(URL);
    return new URI(uri.getScheme(),
                   uri.getAuthority(),
                   uri.getPath(),
                   null,
                   uri.getFragment()).toString();
}
```

Comment: thanks for answer , but how i add the webview.goBack() url to your function ?

Comment: you can't use go back if you want to change URL, instead use load url,  webview.loadUrl(getOnlyURL(YOUR_URL));

Comment: The goback() use url from cache list , if i go back after some user action ; the action is duplicated , like on this link , if i clic on button generate line i have this link : `https://website.com/userpanel/testlines.php?action=new_test_line `             , now if i go back its generated another line , i need goback to the link without the : `?action=new_test_line` ,    this is why i need to modifie url of cache list before goback

Comment: i need something like this ` if (URL.contains("?")) {
                        webview.loadUrl(URL.substring(0, URL.indexOf("?")));
                    }`  but with goback() url cache list